# Уведомление об административной ответственности от Google Play - Notification of administrative action from Google Play

Tags: google-play-console

Вчера получил письмо от Гугл говорящее о том, что мое приложение блокируется в некоторых странах из-за того, что содержит контент запрещенный в этих странах.

> Policy issue: Your app includes content that is prohibited in the above locales.

Что я могу теперь сделать что-бы восстановить свое приложение? Как мне определить какой именно контент запрещен? 
Письмо написал в поддержку, но сомневаюсь, что ответят что-то вразумительное. Приложение уже в маркете 5 лет и с контентом все было в порядке.
Может у кого-то есть такой печальный опыт?

Comment: Иногда самоуправство Гугла сводиться к нечестной/оплаченной им конкуренции. Если приложение занимает приличную нишу в какой то области. Поищите для начала 'конкурентов' в этом сегменте.

Comment: @NewView, а что мне даст поиск конкурентов? Хотя я их знаю в лицо всех...

Comment: Возможно понимание, если регионы где вас забанили и рынки и происхождение конкурентов совпадают

Comment: Гугл сейчас закручивает гайки и проверяет контент приложений (например, у нас полностью удалили одно приложение после двух лет публикации). Надо смотреть, что за регионы и что там может быть запрещено. Как пример: в Китае нельзя изображать скелетов - приложения с этими изображениями тоже недопустимый контент. Хотя мне изначально прислали письмо со скрином - что именно и где мы нарушили

Comment: @Jarvis_J, а ваше приложение после удаления так и не восстановили? В случае удаления, какие могут быть дальнейшие действия? Как вернуть приложение?
Вот вы написали "Надо смотреть, что за регионы и что там может быть запрещено." - регион Россия, приложение касается праздников и событий в России и более нигде. Ума не приложу что могло вызвать такую реакцию. Да и где это можно посмотреть, о запрете то?

Comment: Удалили без права восстановления. Написали: исправьте ошибки и выложите с новым названием пакета. Это была платная версия бесплатного приложения, поэтому мы просто добавили в бесплатную инапп покупки. Перед этим изменили "недопустимый контент", в нашем случае - картинки откровенного содержания). Другие приложения иногда отклоняют обновление (по причине: неясно выраженная рекламная ссылка). Началось примерно с полгода назад, когда на фэйсе начали шерстить странички и банить за "недопустимый контент" (включая лечение и профилактику вен. заболеваний о_О). Мы решили, что ветер с этой стороны дует)

Comment: У вас в вопросе: "в некоторых странах" - это значит в России работает? Если скинете ссылку на приложение, могу в свободное время пробежаться глазами, может пойму что. У меня иногда банят и отклоняют приложения, тоже пытался разбираться, так что общее понимание есть :) хотя всегда с баном присылают скрин ошибки, один раз не прислали - написал в поддержку, что без скрина не понимаю, что нарушил - в течение трёх дней прислали скрин. Там вроде в письме есть ссылка, где уточняющие вопросы задать

Comment: Скачал и посмотрел бесплатную версию) навскидку за что могут банить: язычество (не уверен), свастика, много копипаст (? Пишут, что могут докопаться), возможно внутри тексты про секс, расчленёнку и т.п.). Надо смотреть регионы, где банят

Comment: @Jarvis_J, на счет копипаст я уже думал, но я вроде бы как все условия источников соблюдаю (прямая ссылка, где то прямое уведомление).
И не совсем понятно, про регионы? Написали, что приложение более не доступно в России,Германии, Австрии и Франции.

Comment: Я скачал из ру маркета, у меня всё нормально. Вообще, вот что пишет Гугл: "The policy notification email includes the policy your app violated and the steps you need to take to resolve the issue". В общем надо смотреть изменения политики Гугл (за год+) и просить поддержку разъяснить нарушение. Вот это читали: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy-print/ ? Можно просто попробовать перезалить приложение в новом пакете и надеяться на лучшее :)

Comment: Посмотрел еще раз. Да, возможно, из-за копипасты и ссылок на источники. У Гугл в этом отношении свои правила. Возможно, просто из-за "левых" для Гугла ссылок